# React visjs timeline vertical scroll jumps to the top when changing a property of timeline options

Tags: reactjs, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I have simple react application where I am using react-visjs-timeline. When I change a **movable** property (this property is to allow or block horizontal scroll) of the timeline from options, the vertical scroll jumps back to the top.

It is not only changing movable property but changing any property in the options triggers this issue. The project is available in codesandbox and I would highly appreciate any help or suggestions.

To reproduce the problem:

1. Scroll down the timeline.
2. Click on the button "Lock/Unlock Scroll"

You will immediately notice that the timeline jumps back to the top.

Link to the Project: https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-vistimeline-n18rm6